# Is there a better way to jumper 3 terminals together?

Tags: jumper, screw-terminal, din-rail

I can't find terminal block jumpers for sets of 3 and 5 terminals, just 10 and 2. So I took some 2-terminal jumpers and tried to accomplish what I needed to do but it looks unsightly and seems likely to fail due to the torque induced on adjacent blocks. Is there a better way to gang three and five terminal blocks together? See picture below:

[image: daisy chaining 2-gang terminal blocks]

Comment: There should be a tool for these kind of terminal blocks which helps you to clip a whole row onto the rail nicely. Check the manufacturer's catalogue.

Comment: Wago 222 series connectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use DIN-Rail terminal blocks that have a bussing feature across the top so that I don't have to double up on the wire entry connections.  Different manufacturers have both pluggable and screw down bussing arrangements.  As an  alternative to what you show in your photo, you can buy a comb bussbar that joins more than two at a time.  Buy a 10-position bussbar and then cut to length for less than 10.

Comment: would you mind recommending one with a bussing feature? still having trouble finding an actual match to the terminal blocks I have

Comment: Most major terminal mfrs. make these: Phoenix (ex: UK5, UT4), AB (ex:1492), Wago, etc.  If your business purchases enough of these you probably have a distributor saleperson visiting now and then...hit her up for specifics.  Otherwise check out online sources such as Allied, Mouser, DigiKey, AutomationDirect...